# The function below does not remove the RT tags from the tweets. I want to remove 'b' and 'RT' both from the tweets. Any help will be appreciated

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, python-re

The head of my dataframe looks like this

[image]

I am using 're' library of pandas and I have written my code as below.

```
for i in df.index:
txt = df.loc[i]["tweet"]
txt=re.sub(r'@[A-Z0-9a-z_:]+','',txt)#replace username-tags
txt=re.sub(r'^[RT]+','',txt)#replace RT-tags
txt = re.sub('https?://[A-Za-z0-9./]+','',txt)#replace URLs
txt=re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ",txt)#replace hashtags
df.at[i,"tweet"]=txt
```

However, running this does not remove the 'RT' tag. In addition, I would like to remove the 'b' tag also.

Comment: 89 is not in your index of df. Do `for i in df.index`

Comment: editing your question and leaving the error messages of the previous code doesn't help.

Comment: @It_is_Chris Thanks for the solution Chris, Appreciate it.

Comment: @liberforce Apologies, I have changed it now.

Comment: Is this fixed? ..

Comment: @RobertHarvey Chirs had answered my index problem, however, the 'RT' tag is not getting removed.